# Filtering a list of dictionaries by a list of substrings

Tags: python, flask

Having spent the morning looking at similar questions, I need a little help finishing my filter on a list of dictionaries.

I have a list of dictionaries returned from an API call that I want to filter to return the lists where the 'name' value contains certain substrings.

The following code half works.. it returns only the job.names that contain the final substring in the list: ("-upload").

```
def filter():
    list_of_dicts = server.get_jobs()
    foo = ["-cb", "-audit", "-upload"]
    for f in foo:
        filtered = [d for d in list_of_dicts if f in d["name"]
    return render_template("testing.html", jobs=filtered)
```

For the sake of completeness this is passed to:

```
{% for job in jobs %}
   <p>Job: {{job.name}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

I have tried initialising an empty list before the for loop and appending the filtered variable to it, however I always get the error = 'generator object' has no attribute 'items':

```
def filter():
    list_of_dicts = server.get_jobs()
    foo = ["-cb", "-audit", "-upload"]
    for f in foo:
        result = []
        filtered = [d for d in list_of_dicts if f in d["name"]
        result.append(filtered)
    return render_template("testing.html", jobs=result)
```

Comment: Instead of creating `filtered` in a loop: `filtered=[d for d in list_of_dicts if any(f in d["name"] for f in foo]`

Comment: This works, however as there is a job in list_of_dicts with each of the substrings (job1-cb, job1-audit, job1-upload)  I'm getting repeated values for each result (job1-cb x3 , job1-audit x 3, job1-upload x3). Any ideas?

Comment: @Gillespie if you don't want the repeats, make it a `set` instead of a `list` comprehension. Just change it to `filtered = { d for d ... }`

Comment: @dwanderson Returns unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: Ah, right, it's returning the dict, not just the key. I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to either create a list without adding duplicates, or to make a set of keys and use them as desired, since those are different solutions for different cases, and I don't know which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are overwriting your result list in each iteration of the following loop

```
for f in foo:
    filtered = [d for d in list_of_dicts if f in d["name"]
```

So filtered holds result of only last `f` that is `'-upload'`You need to do

```
filtered = list()
for f in foo:
    filtered.extend([d for d in list_of_dicts if f in d["name"])
```